# Bootstrap tooltip with HTML in a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am attempting to append a table to a div I've created. In this table I would like to add a bootstrap tool-tip with some HTML and css classes. When doing so my output always returns my HTML as the text display. I am having issues with trying to create the output I am looking for.

When adding HTML to the bootstrap tooltip are you able to do so in a string?

Here is an example of my code:

```js
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
 
 
 let html = ""
 
html += '<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="left" title="<div class="row"><p>hello world</p></div>"> Test HTML </a >';

 $("#tooltipData").html(html);
```

```css
.row {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id='tooltipData'>
</div>

<br/> 
<br/>

<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="left" title="<div class='row'>hello world</div>"> Test HTML </a >
```

The first div `tooltipData` is an example of the issues that I am having.

The second `<a>` data is an example of the tooltip working as expected, but I am unable to get that same result from the first example `tooltipData`.

My expected result is to append to the div and have the same output as `<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="left" title="<div class='row'><p>hello world</p> </div>" Test </a >`

I am expecting to hover over the first "Test HTML" and have the tooltip read `hello world` as the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do it using `\'` to quote the row.  But you also must make sure  `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` renders after your addition of the html code in js.  See here:

```js
let html = ""
 
html += '<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="left" title="<div class=\'row\' >ok</div>"> Test HTML </a >';

 $("#tooltipData").html(html);
 
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

```css
.row {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id='tooltipData'>
</div>



<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="left" title="<div class='row'>ok</div>"> Test HTML </a >
```